# Line thickness when plotting discrete points

Tags: matlab, plot

I am plotting a circle plot and calculating the coordinates of the circle myself.

E.g.

```
my_vector=0:0.1:2*pi;
for i=1:length(my_vector),
    plot(...,'LineWidth',3);
    ...%some other functions like
    my_fill=fill(...)
    pause
    delete(my_fill)
end
```

There is no effect of `LineWidth`. I even tried 20

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you plotting one point at a time?

Can you do something like this?

```
plot(x_coord, y_coord, 'k.', 'markersize', 20)
```

This provides a circle of points:

```
my_vector=0:0.1:2*pi;
for ii = 1:length(my_vector)
  x = cos(ii);
  y = sin(ii);
  plot(x,y, 'k.', 'markersize', 10)
  hold on
end
```